# mysql_query(): 3 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource?

Tags: php, mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Warning: mysql_query(): 3 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851420/warning-mysql-query-3-is-not-a-valid-mysql-link-resource)

I don't know why the $GUconnection resource isn't working on queries since I set it up as a global variable. The db connection is

```
$GUconnection = mysql_connect(serverip, username, password);
@mysql_select_db(dbname, $GUconnection) or die('Cannot connect to the database.');
```

The following query is located in an include file that is included in the file containing the mysql connection above:

```
global $GUconnection;    
$GUresult = mysql_query("SELECT field FROM `tablename` WHERE field = 'hey' LIMIT 1", $GUconnection);            
                if(mysql_num_rows($GUresult)) {
                    $GUfile = mysql_fetch_assoc($GUresult);   

                }
```

The errors I got where

```
Warning: mysql_query(): 3 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /home/ on line 49

Warning: mysql_num_rows(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in /home/ on line 50
```

If I don't have the include and just paste the query directly underneath the connection then it works. What seems to be the problem?

Comment: the connection parameter is optional, try to remove it temporarily and see if query works.

Comment: I also have another connection so I think it's wise to keep it?

Comment: The mysql extension is so out of date it's not worth trying to fix this code. [PDO](http://php.net/PDO) is simpler, extensible and has better features. Also [globals are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad). Better is to create a class whose sole responsibility is managing DB connections, or use [dependency injection](http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

Comment: This might look trivial but is `$GUconnection` global where you do `mysql_connect`?

Comment: Basically I took outis' advice and implemented the same thing in PDO and everything is working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feel the power of google.

While writing your question on SO brings you no help, exact error message pasted into google's search box finds you complete solution. In much less time.

Comment: I did, it wasn't any problem I found on Google. Turns out it was an interference with another connection. Anyways, I implemented this using PDO and it works now.

Comment: Dude, it's first link from google which a posted above. Are you sure you looked for this certain problem, not something else?

Answer (score 0):

The connection may fail, so you should check for connection errors.

Comment: The connection works. I just can't access it elsewhere