# MYSQL supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource

Tags: php, mysql, select

ERROR:

```
Warning: mysql_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /var/www/247QC/system/core.php on line 21
Invalid query: Whole query: SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='matt' AND password='5657572fc913e2d2a9548ba4f4'
```

From my knowledge I have not done anything wrong in my code but I thought I would ask, since the last time I used `MySQL` was 2 years ago, things might of changed.

I am wondering what is the error and how do i fix it, I am at the point after googling for the last hour and results saying it was a connection issue and after testing it was connecting to the server correctly (using the hostname not IP address)

The `MySQL` engine it is using is `InnoDB` and Collation `latin1_swedish_ci`

code

```
$r_hostname = "monitor";
$r_username = "QCSYSTEM";
$r_password = "123456";
$link = mysql_connect($r_hostname,$r_username,$r_password);
$db = mysql_select_db('QCSYSTEM', $link);

$Password = sha1($_POST['password']);
$username = $_POST['username'];


$query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='%s' AND password='%s'",
         mysql_real_escape_string($username),
         mysql_real_escape_string($Password));
$result = mysql_query($query,$db);                  

if (!$result) {
    $message  = 'Invalid query: ' . mysql_error() . "\n";
    $message .= 'Whole query: ' . $query;
    die($message);
} else {
    print "success";                            
}
```

Comment: Your link to the database server is not being established. Check for the return value of `mysql_connect`. Are you sure the host name is `monitor` ? Try `localhost` if unsure

Comment: Here same Question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851420/warning-mysql-query-3-is-not-a-valid-mysql-link-resource
and instead of $db, you must be passing $link in Mysql Query

Comment: $db is just selecting the database not the connection, in your situation it's $link, why not us PDO or similar?

Answer (score 3):

The second argument to `mysql_query` should be a link identifier. You are using `$db` as the second argument, which is nothing but a boolean value. Try this..

```
$result = mysql_query($query,$link);
```

or just don't pass any second argument.