# 2 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource. How to fix? Same script works on another server (not dub since it works on other server)

Tags: php, mysql, database

1st of all I'd like to underline the fact that same script does work on another server and never throws the error. So it's not something inside the script, but something in the server config / mysql connections. So there is no answer in the topic mistakenly suggested by some people here.

Something that I don't know, but I need an advice.

So I copied a script from another server (live website, everything works) to my new droplet (VPS) on digitalocean (centos 6.4 x64) with installed vestacp (sort of free alternative to cpanel / plesk). Same script (100% working on one server).

So the error "2 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource" appeared. Same script, copied files using wget -m.

So I guess the reason should be somewhere in mysql configs, but have no idea where and what that error is about. Please advice.

Tried to reupload all script files from my pc, still same error. So script should work (as it works on another server and on my local server too), but it doesn't on my DO droplet.

Problem solved by using pconnect.

To all smart dudes that flagged my topic as duplicate - you are not always right.

Comment: Look for the DB access details. If you don't know what's this, then your questions does not belong to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Is the error connected to a line number? can you paste that line here?

Comment: So the problem is that we don't see any code. Or the line.

Comment: `$Res=mysql_query($query,$GLOBALS['htracer_mysql_link']);` this line is where error appears. The problem is as I said 100% same script works absolutely fine (no errors) on another server (cpanel). Si I suppose it's not a code problem, but some mysql config problem. And yes, I did read another topics, but since it's not what I'm looking for I've decided to create a topic.

Answer (score 1):

If the database connection fails you'll likely get a "Specified variable is not a valid MySQL-Link resource" error,

```
$link = mysql_connect('localsoth','baduser','badpass'); // failed connection
$result = mysql_query("SELECT 1", $link); // throws error
```

Since you're getting a specific resource ID in the error message, the database connection likely closed unexpectedly for some reason. Your program still has a variable with a resource ID, but the external object no longer exists. This may be due to a mysql_close() call somewhere before the call to mysql_query, or an external database error that closed the connection.

```
$link = mysql_connect();
mysql_close($link);
// $link may still contain a resource identifier, but the external object is gone
mysql_query("SELECT 1", $link);
```

Please go trough the link mentioned by @nrathaus which is [Warning: mysql_query(): 3 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851420/warning-mysql-query-3-is-not-a-valid-mysql-link-resource)

Comment: `$Res=mysql_query($query,$GLOBALS['htracer_mysql_link']);`   this line is where error appears. The problem is as I said 100% same script works absolutely fine (no errors) on another server (cpanel). Si I suppose it's not a code problem, but some mysql config problem. And yes, I did read another topics, but since it's not what I'm looking for I've decided to create a topic.

Answer (score 0):

Your error appears to be quite common a simple search revealed: [Warning: mysql_query(): 3 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851420/warning-mysql-query-3-is-not-a-valid-mysql-link-resource) Yes his error number is 3, yours is 2, that is because of pointer assignments in PHP, they are the same error/problem and solution.

Comment: I edited first post, so everyone can see that it's different. I'm not looking into "how to fix the script", since I have it working on another server. So I assume script is fine, but server config is not.