# updating a date format in mysql based on empty date field

Tags: mysql

I have a cloclin program where studnets are clocked in and out. If a student is not clocked out by 6:30 PM at the end of the day I have a mysql statement that executes and clocks the student out at 6:30pm automatically to help keep the tables clean.

When a student is clocked into the system it fills the start time with the proper time and the end time is left as "0000-00-00 00:00:00". I am having a hard time determining the sql statement to detect the emtpty EndTime field to determine if it is blank. Since by default the table lists the blank date field as 0000-00-00 00:00:00" the CONCAT method I use to update the field seems to work when updating the field, but does not work to determine the criteria "WHERE"

My current sql statement is

```
$sql = "UPDATE `daycare attendance table` SET EndTime = CONCAT('1899-12-30 ', '18:30:00') WHERE EndTime = CONCAT('0000-00-00 ', '00:00:00')";
```

I also tried

```
$sql = "UPDATE `daycare attendance table` SET EndTime = CONCAT('1899-12-30 ', '18:30:00') WHERE EndTime = ''";
```

and

```
$sql = "UPDATE `daycare attendance table` SET EndTime = CONCAT('1899-12-30 ', '18:30:00') WHERE EndTime IS NULL";
```

The script just errors out as

```
Warning: mysql_db_query(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in...
```

any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Warning: mysql\_query(): 3 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2851420/warning-mysql-query-3-is-not-a-valid-mysql-link-resource)

Answer (score 0):

Since it runs daily, you could just say `where end_time < now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR and start_time >= now() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR;`

Ok, updated a sample fiddle for you using timestamp -> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bbdfe/1

Probly the best thing to do is to change your default from '0000-00-00 00:00:00' which isn't valid for a timestamp field to a valid time -> 1970+ and all your problems will then go away.

Comment: thats not going to work because if would update every record that has a EndTime listed since all the EndTimes will be < NOW() :) It has to determine if the EndTime field is blank or has no time

Comment: but I suppose that's basically the same as where start_time > end_time.  LOL, anyway, hopefully some of the fiddles give you some ideas.

Comment: that is not going to work either because the start time will always be < NOW(). Start time is past tense. Isnt there a way to determine the field being blank or no time at all? "000-00-00 00:00:00"?

Comment: I don't think you've looked at any of my examples.  I've given you at least 3 workable solutions.  At this point you're just being obstinate.